# Translation for "consistently low quality questions over time" mod template isn't used

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, moderator-templates

Existing translation not used for mod template "consistently low quality questions over time".

There are [two original sentences](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=There%20are%20a%20number%20of%20potential%20reason). I don't really know which one should be used, but no one is actually used.

Full English text that is currently visible instead of necessary translation located below:

> We really want you to have a good experience here, and the first step
> to that is making sure that questions you submit are clear, on topic
> and provide all of the information someone would need to answer. You
> may have noticed that questions you’ve asked weren’t well received by
> the community; they were downvoted and closed.
>
> Specifically, we would like to highlight these questions:
>
> There are a number of potential reasons for this and we’d like to help
> you diagnose exactly what’s happening. Questions may be downvoted and
> closed because they fit one of our [closure
> criteria](/help/closed-questions), or are of the [type that we’d
> prefer users refrain from asking](/help/dont-ask). While we’re excited
> that you’re contributing, we ask that you please take some time to
> read the information linked below - prior to asking another question -
> in order to assure the best possible experience (both for yourself,
> and also for other community members):
>
> - A brief [guide on how to ask questions](/help/how-to-ask)
> - A short summary of [questions we permit](/help/on-topic)
>
> {optionalSuspensionAutoMessage}